# Dynamic IP assignment in theory

Tags: router, ip, isp, dynamic-ip

If I turn my router off for 24 hours or more I am always assigned a new dynamic IP address once I turn it on again.

Theoretical question for you guys; Does that mean I don't actually have an assigned IP address if I turn my home router off for a few days (given that it changes when when the router is off for 24 hours)

Comment: Your terminology for "assigned an IP address" is very loose and ambiguous.. It seems that after X hours they remove the association between your MAC and the IP they gave you, and assign or are ready to assign that IP to somebody else.  It sounds a bit like they flush their own memory, I don't know the technical term for the process.

Comment: Are you asking if your person devices in your home network get dynamic IPs or the routers assigned IP from your ISP? The router both received a dynamic IP was well as issues dynamic IPs to your internal home devices that are connected to it.

Answer (score 0):

Tt depends how much you pay to your ISP! You pay more, you can get static IP.
Your dynamic IP depends to your ISP configuration on its DHCP server. Your dynamic IP been shared with few other users, so when you go out, someone else will replace you unless there is no new client request.

Answer (score 0):

If you have dynamic IP addresses from your ISP, then you **never** have an "assigned IP address".  If your router is on, they lend you an IP address for a specific amount of time.  At the end of that time, if you're still using it, it gets renewed.  If you aren't still using it (because your router is off), then it gets returned to the pool.  Next time you turn on your router, they lend you a new IP address.